# Sorting list according to previous order

Tags: scala

In code below the `List` ordering of `val originalOrdering` should be re-created after removing element(s) from the `List`.

If `val random3ElementStringList` takes value `List(3, 4, 1)` then List should be re-ordered to `List(1 , 3 , 4)`
The original list `val originalOrdering` with values `1,2,3,4` does not suggest the values that can be contained in the `List`. The list can contain characters other than numeric.

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

object sort extends App {

    val originalOrdering : List[String] = List("1" , "2" , "3" , "4");

    var random3ElementStringList : List[String] = util.Random.shuffle(originalOrdering).take(3)

    val stringPositions : Map[String , Int] = originalOrdering.zipWithIndex.toMap

    println(random3ElementStringList)

    println(stringPositions);

    val fl = random3ElementStringList.foldLeft("")((a , b) => (stringPositions.get(b)+","))

    println(fl)

}
```

The output of this code is :

```
List(2, 3, 4)
Map(1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3)
Some(3),
```

But `fl` should contain the sentences in sorted order where the sort is determined by the original order in `stringPositions`

Update :

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

object sort extends App {

    def reOrder(originalList : List[String] , originalListSubset : List[String]) = {

        val stringPositions : Map[String , Int] = originalList.zipWithIndex.toMap
        val fl : List[(String , Int)] = originalListSubset.map(m => (m , stringPositions.get(m).get))

        fl.sortBy(s => s._2).map(m => m._1)
    }

    val originalList : List[String] = List("a" , "b" , "c" , "f");
    var random3ElementStringList : List[String] = util.Random.shuffle(originalList).take(3)

    println(random3ElementStringList)
    println(reOrder(originalList , random3ElementStringList))

    random3ElementStringList = util.Random.shuffle(originalList).take(2)

    println(random3ElementStringList)
    println(reOrder(originalList , random3ElementStringList))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to use `a` in the folding function. It's the "accumulator" of the folding. You can fix it like this:

```
val fl = random3ElementStringList.foldLeft("") { (acc, index) =>
  acc +","+ stringPositions.get(index)
}
```

I changed the arguments names to make it more clear. Here's output:

```
List(3, 4, 2)
Map(1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3)
,Some(2),Some(3),Some(1)
```

You can get rid of that comma in the beginning, but I would suggest you a simpler solution without `foldLeft`:

```
val fl = random3ElementStringList.map(stringPositions.get).mkString(",")
```

You can just map over those random indexes and get the elements, then make a string with a given separator. The output is `Some(2),Some(3),Some(1)`.

Comment: thanks, I extended your code and posted an update to question. New version sorts the modified map keys where the sort position is determined by the order, realized this after implementing your update. thanks!

Comment: I didn't quite get it. With this updated code do you have a new question?